# Unable to open PulseAudio in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, pulseaudio

I have CentOS 7.4.1708 x64 on my VPS. As I try to open `pulseaudio` via terminal I get this error message:

```
[jjjjj@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio  E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running. E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

How can I solve this?

Response to the answer :

```
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --kill 
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --start 
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ cd $HOME 
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ mkdir .pulse 
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --start E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed. 
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --kill E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process 
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio E: [pulseau
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to correct the terminal transcript (by adding the linebreaks that belong).

Comment: the pulseaudio user directory = `~/.config/pulse`

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the daemon was not killed properly.

First run

```
pulseaudio --kill
```

then

```
pulseaudio --start
```

Also make sure you have your `.pulseaudio` folder in home.

```
cd $HOME
mkdir .pulse
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but am afraid that has not solved the problem,this is what happens                                         
 [jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --kill
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --start
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ cd $HOME
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ mkdir .pulse
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio --kill
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
[jhon453@centos-c-2-nyc1-01 ~]$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseau

Comment: The first time you killed and started, it started without errors, why start again when it has been already started, seems to me like that was the problem @james47

Comment: It was the good solution for me. Useful command: `pulseaudio -vvvv`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `pulseaudio` (& `alsa`) become configured with the volume muted. The solution is to install `pulseaudio-utils` (or `alsa-utils` to use `alsamixer` in a terminal) & check that sound is not muted.

On a minimal Centos 7 installation I needed to unmute the output device in the **PulseAudio Volume Control**:

[image: PulseAudio with output device volume muted]

The PulseAudio user directory is also found in `~/.config/pulse` not `~/.pulse`